# I have extra space on the right side of my page and I can't get rid of it

Tags: html, css

So I have a responsive web page which is completely fine when it is full screen. However when I minimise my the screen to a max-width of 500px I have extra space on the right side. Somewhere in my code is causing this and I can't spot the problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Navbar */

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #945A53;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #E0BAB6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background: #E0BAB6;
  color: #945A53;
}


/* Welcome section */

main {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #406599;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #E0BAB6;
}

#title p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #E0BAB6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #title {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}


/* Project section */

.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: #406599;
}

#project-section {
  background-color: #D1E098;
}

.header {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#projects {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.project-tile {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

.img {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #406599;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.btn {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #406599;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #406599;
  color: #E0BAB6;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#btn-icon {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #E0BAB6;
  color: #406599;
  border-color: #E0BAB6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #navbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #665A5A;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #welcome-section {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #title {
    padding: ;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  #title p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}


/* Contact section */

#contact-section {
  background-color: #8DB0E0;
}

#contact h2 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #945A53;
}

#contact p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #945A53;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px;
}

#icon {
  text-align: center;
  color: #945A53;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  animation-name: icon;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes icon {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}

#item {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: #945A53;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #contact h2 {
    font-size: 3.8rem;
  }
  #item {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
}

footer {
  background-color: #8DB0E0;
  padding: 40px;
  color: #945A53;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .footer {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&family=Signika+Negative:wght@600&family=Zen+Antique+Soft&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<nav id="navbar">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<main>

  <section id="welcome-section">
    <div id="title">
      <h1 id="about">Hello there, I'm Tamanna</h1>
      <p>A front-end developer</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="project-section">
    <h3 class="header">These are some of my projects</h3>

    <div id="projects">
      <div class="flex-container">

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/NWvvjeJ" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/NWvvjeJ/image/small.png" alt="Cameron Boyce">
            <div class="caption">Tribute Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/GRvOQPE" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/GRvOQPE/image/small.png" alt="Survey form">
            <div class="caption">Survey Form Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/porpEVN" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/porpEVN/image/small.png" alt="Product landing page">
            <div class="caption">Product Landing Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/KKveMRy" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/KKveMRy/image/small.png" alt="Technical Documentation Page">
            <div class="caption">Technical Documentation Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams" class="btn" target="_blank">Show all <span id="btn-icon" class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact-section">
    <div id="contact">
      <h2>Let's work together...</h2>
      <p>How would you like for us to meet?</p>

      <div id="icon">
        <span id="item" class="fab fa-codepen icon"><a class="text" href="#">Codepen</a></span>
        <span id="item" class="fab fa-github icon"><a class="text" href="#">Github</a></span>
        <span id="item" class="fas fa-at icon"><a class="text" href="#">Send a email</a></span>
        <span id="item" class="fab fa-linkedin"><a class="text" href="#">LinkedIn</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>

<footer>
  <p class="footer">&copy; Created for freeCodeCamp</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: If you upload html. It will be more easy to resolve your problem.

Comment: Can you provide HTML too ? Also you have unset property `#title { padding: ; }`

Comment: Probably this `.flex-container {  width: 1100px;` cause the issue

Comment: @Niko i have added the html

Comment: @amoong i have added the html

Comment: next time pelase cut the code down to the minimal part that is causing the issue. Remove part of the code, see if the issue is gone. If the issue is gone, copy back the code, if it is not, start back at removing some part. Cutting the code down to the aprt that is causing the issue is the first step of debugging yourself. Asking others to look through over 500 lines of code can be considered excessive.

Comment: `img {max-width:100%}` Maybe ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 probably not, its parent is also a flex container  which is not set on `flex-wrap:wrap`   and `.flex-container`  has also  `flex-shrink`   **not reset to 0** , it should shrink even if the size set is wider with these  *flex* setting.

Answer (score 1):

Inbetween `product landing page` and `technical documentation page` in your HTML is an image, a screenshot. This is forcing the wider view. As you can see in mobile view that images continues to be the full width of the screen. if you shrink it or use some `overflow` commands everything should fall back in line.

Comment: Thank you! I minimised the size of the image screen with media queries and it got rid of the extra space

Comment: @TamannaHoque Great, good work! In Bootstrap, one really good way to ensure images stay in line is to use `class="img-fluid` on the `<img>` so that it reads `<img src="..." class="img-fluid">`. That will mean the image stays exctly the width of it's parent Div without the need for extra CSS or media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Overflow seems to be from img being wider than the screen at one point.

A fix could be for the pictures linked in your projects :

```
#projects a img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Your settings are actually :

```
.img {
  width: 450px;/* this becomes too much at one point */
  height: 300px; /* its fine as long as img is 150px of width, less and distorsion appears */
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
/* fix */
#projects a img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
/* end fix */ 


html {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Navbar */

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #945A53;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #E0BAB6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background: #E0BAB6;
  color: #945A53;
}


/* Welcome section */

main {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #406599;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #E0BAB6;
}

#title p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #E0BAB6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #title {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}


/* Project section */

.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: #406599;
}

#project-section {
  background-color: #D1E098;
}

.header {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#projects {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.project-tile {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 30px;
}

.img {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #406599;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.btn {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #406599;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #406599;
  color: #E0BAB6;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#btn-icon {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #E0BAB6;
  color: #406599;
  border-color: #E0BAB6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #navbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #665A5A;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #welcome-section {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #title {
    padding: ;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  #title p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}


/* Contact section */

#contact-section {
  background-color: #8DB0E0;
}

#contact h2 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #945A53;
}

#contact p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #945A53;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px;
}

#icon {
  text-align: center;
  color: #945A53;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  animation-name: icon;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes icon {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}

#item {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: #945A53;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #contact h2 {
    font-size: 3.8rem;
  }
  #item {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  .text {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
}

footer {
  background-color: #8DB0E0;
  padding: 40px;
  color: #945A53;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .footer {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&family=Signika+Negative:wght@600&family=Zen+Antique+Soft&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<nav id="navbar">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<main>

  <section id="welcome-section">
    <div id="title">
      <h1 id="about">Hello there, I'm Tamanna</h1>
      <p>A front-end developer</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="project-section">
    <h3 class="header">These are some of my projects</h3>

    <div id="projects">
      <div class="flex-container">

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/NWvvjeJ" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/NWvvjeJ/image/small.png" alt="Cameron Boyce">
            <div class="caption">Tribute Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/GRvOQPE" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/GRvOQPE/image/small.png" alt="Survey form">
            <div class="caption">Survey Form Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/porpEVN" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/porpEVN/image/small.png" alt="Product landing page">
            <div class="caption">Product Landing Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="project-tile" id="work">
          <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/KKveMRy" class="profile-tile" target="_blank">
            <img class="img" src="https://codepen.io/itstams/pen/KKveMRy/image/small.png" alt="Technical Documentation Page">
            <div class="caption">Technical Documentation Page</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <a href="https://codepen.io/itstams" class="btn" target="_blank">Show all <span id="btn-icon" class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact-section">
    <div id="contact">
      <h2>Let's work together...</h2>
      <p>How would you like for us to meet?</p>

      <div id="icon">
        <span id="item" class="fab fa-codepen icon"><a class="text" href="#">Codepen</a></span>
        <span id="item" class="fab fa-github icon"><a class="text" href="#">Github</a></span>
        <span id="item" class="fas fa-at icon"><a class="text" href="#">Send a email</a></span>
        <span id="item" class="fab fa-linkedin"><a class="text" href="#">LinkedIn</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>

<footer>
  <p class="footer">&copy; Created for freeCodeCamp</p>
</footer>
```

note : that overflow:hidden; can cut it off too

```
#project-section {
  background-color: #D1E098;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the images are too big when you minimise the screen, so I reduced the sizes of the images with media queries! Thanks for your help!